# Term for providing a rationale for why a concept applies

Tags: phrase-requests

I am using a concept that was developed for one subject area and applying it to a different area. However, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the objects in the original concept and the objects in the area I would like to apply it to.

Specifically, I am drawing an analogy between voters in a shareholder meeting (where not everyone has the same voting power) and chemicals at a Superfund site, in that both carry a certain weight (votes/health risk) towards a measure (bill/remedial action decision).

I would like to introduce this discussion with a section header that quickly describes that I will be providing a rationale for applicability of the specific concept. Right now, I am using the provisional title *Rationale for Applicability*, but perhaps there is something "preposition-free" or more descriptive?

Comment: *Applicability* comes with its inherent sense of its *rationale*, why the redundancy?

Comment: "I will discuss the Applicability of the Concept." (i.e., why it is claimed to be applicable, suitable, appropriate, or the necessary-&-sufficient process)

Comment: @Kris Thanks...that's what I was leaning towards...I'm simply using Applicability as the section heading as it is objous what I referring to the applicability of from prior sections. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Kris' response:

> Applicability comes with its inherent sense of its rationale, why the redundancy?

Applicability would be understood as providing a rationale, so I will simply use that.

Comment: @choster That answer is not posted for accepting so I referenced it in my answer so I can close out the question.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. But in that case, you ought to reproduce the full answer and then self-accept; otherwise, it sends the return visitor on a hunt to find where the correct answer actually lies.

Comment: @choster edited per your comment.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: You didn't actually mark this as accepted. If you mark it as accepted it makes it a lot more clear that it answered your question adequately.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation! 
Simple and straight forward enough; correlation may have degrees, or be one-to one. . .

Answer (score 0):

**Analogy**, as you used yourself is a good word for that.

**Parable** is another word, which means a similar story for demonstrating something. But is *generally* used in a moral context. Although I don't see why it can not be applied in a scientific situation.